# Extract text from caret position textarea

Tags: wpf, textarea, extract, caret

I am having trouble to extract text from textarea using WPF code behind.

Example:
Sunny day in London

if the cursor is set on [d*ay] it should return day.
* for the cursor.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite your example.  Is * the caret position?  If the caret is in that position you want to return what string exactly, "day"?

Comment: Exactly I want to get back [day]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work but I am not sure how you want it to behave when the caret is in the middle of whitespace.  As is, it basically returns the nearest token that is touching the caret.  For example, the phrase "Sunny day in London" has four tokens: "Sunny", "day", "in", and "London".

```
string selection;

if (txtBox.Text.Length > 0)
{
    int startIndex = 0;

    for (int i = txtBox.CaretIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text[i].ToString()))
        {
            startIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    int length = txtBox.Text.Length - startIndex;

    for (int i = startIndex; startIndex + i <= txtBox.Text.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text[startIndex + i].ToString()))
        {
            length = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    selection = txtBox.Text.Substring(startIndex, length);
}
else
{
    selection = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I guess I forgot to mention that I am working with RichTextBox using WPF, your solution seems to apply for textbox.